# Равномерное распределение числа на сутки

Tags: php

У меня с равным промежутком времени должна выполняться функция в цикле.
Требуется распределить число (1000 - количество выполнений функции) на сутки (24 часа - время, за которое пройдет 1000 выполнений).

Comment: В сутках 86400 секунд. При делении на 1000 - получается 86,4 секунды.

Comment: Настрой cron на выполнение своей функции каждые 86 секунд

Answer (score 0):

Если сделать в цикле тогда код будет:

```
<?php
      while (1)
      {
            //all code
            sleep(86.4);
      }
?>
```

Но лучше использовать [CRON](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) и задать ему выполнять скрипт через определенное время, в данном случае через 86.4 секунды.